# scheduling job with at specifying timezone - "refusing to create job destined in the past"

Tags: time, time-zone, at

I'm trying to specify a timezone for `at` so I can use it in a bash script and not have to worry about adjusting it twice a year, and getting this error:

> at: refusing to create job destined in the past

Where am I going wrong?

---

What time is it now? (the UK has just gone from BST -> GMT/UTC for the winter)

```
$ date
Sun 25 Oct 2020 11:00:11 AM GMT
```

This should be in about 5 minutes...

```
$ at 11:05 UTC
at: refusing to create job destined in the past
```

Try the named timezone of the server…
(I actually get this with any timezone I can think of - e.g. CET, EST, EDT, CST, PST, PDT, AEST... - the docs in */usr/share/doc/at/timespec* just say "time_base timezone_name")

```
$ at 11:05 GMT
syntax error. Last token seen: G
Garbled time
```

Finally to demonstrate it works normally without any timezone..

```
$ at 11:05
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at>

[...]
```

---

at version 3.1.23
Debian 10.6

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518292/46970), `at` uses the local time as set by the `TZ` environment variable.  Thus you can do:

For UTC:

```bsh
TZ=UTC at 11:05
```

Or for the UK using GMT/BST as applicable:

```bsh
TZ=Europe/London at 11:05
```